# JigoShop WordPress hidden value submission

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, fabricjs, jigoshop

I have been toiling with this issue for the past 2 days now, and I can't seem to get some functionality working on a customization for a WordPress plugin. I am using latest versions of both JigoShop and WordPress.

***URL to project:*** http://customcasing.ca/product/ipad-case/
**Current Functionality**

I have 5 product SKUs on the homepage and when clicked lead to their respective product order pages. On these respective pages are a design canvas which I have implemented fabricjs to handle image manipulation. When the user is satisfied, they save the canvas, which then uses the following example code to serialize the image into a JSON object:

[saving/loading canvas with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272772/fabricjs-how-to-save-canvas-on-server-with-custom-attributes/)

The JSON object is then set as the value of a hidden input within the "Add to cart" form. Then they would be able to choose product color variations, via dropdown boxes.

---

**Now here is where things fall apart**

Submitting the "Add to cart" form  is supposed to run through a number of classes and post the hidden JSON object value to an aggregated "cart" object. This is called on various pages and a key/value pair is associated with the various attributes of the product. However, all the other key/value pairs are being executed and echo'd on a subsequent order review page...except my custom variable.

**Here is the directory architecture**

- /wp-content

  - ...
  - /plugins

    - ...
    - /jigoshop

      - jigoshop_template_functions.php
      - jigoshop_actions.php
      - /classes

        - jigoshop_cart.class.php
  - /themes

    - /customcasing

**Here are the code blocks associated with the above structure (pastebin)**

jigoshop_template_functions.php
[html generator and form](http://pastebin.com/TdGJDNvp)

jigoshop_actions.php
[form $_post for hidden field](http://pastebin.com/Tb1hbHy4)

classes/jigoshop_cart.class.php
[form validation and key/value pair creation](http://pastebin.com/XXF0HV8P)

---

I have given as much information as I possibly can about my current conditions, if there were to be anything of help on stackoverflow it would be the following Q/A:

[Trying to send a hidden input value to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843494/trying-to-send-a-hidden-input-value-to-next-page)

If you need any additional information please feel free to ask and I will do my best to elaborate. Also if you need a wider scope of the code I can provide that as well. I would really appreciate any nudge in the right direction.